# Flask SERVER_NAME setting best pratices

Tags: python, email, flask, nginx-reverse-proxy, celery-task

Since my app has background tasks, I use the Flask context. For the context to work, the Flask setting `SERVER_NAME` should be set.

When the `SERVER_NAME` is set the incoming requests are checked to match this value or the route isn't found. When placing an nginx (or other webserver in front), the `SERVER_NAME` should also include the port and the reverse proxy should handle the rewrite stuff, hiding the port number from the outside world (which it does).

For session cookies to work in modern browsers, the URL name passed by the proxy should be the same as the `SERVER_NAME`, otherwise the browser refuses to send the cookies. This can be solved by adding the official `hostname` in the `/etc/hosts` and setting it to `127.0.0.1`.

There is one thing that I haven't figured out yet and it is the URL in the background tasks. `url_for()` is used with the `_external` option to generate URLs in the mail it sends out. But that URL includes the port, which is different from the `443` port used by my nginx instance.

Removing the port from the `SERVER_NAME` makes the stuff described in the first paragraph fail.

So what are my best options for handling the `url_for` in the mail. Create a separate config setting? Create my own `url_for`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `url_for(location, _external=True)`
or include `proxy_params` if you use nginx.